# Is it possible to have a non-zooming region on a html page on an iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

In the email app on the iPhone you can zoom in and out on an email. The email content zooms but the email heading (to/from/subject etc) doesn't zoom.

Is it possible to have a non-zooming region like that with a web app on the iPhone?